# C# Form App do not write in Win 7 Virtual Store

Tags: c#, windows-7, virtualstore

I have a Winfom app created in VS 2012, just has a button which calls below code.
If I run the app in Admin mode(Run As Admin) it is able to create the folder. 
But in non-admin mode(double click on the exe in explorer), it always pops up standard "Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\DirTest' is denied" error.

My doubt is, why its not write in Win 7 Virtual Store when running the app in non-admin mode, whats is missing?

```
`string programFiles = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles);
        string appDir = Path.Combine(programFiles, "DirTest");

        if (Directory.Exists(appDir))
            MessageBox.Show(appDir + " does exists!!!");
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(appDir + " does NOT exists!!!");
            Directory.CreateDirectory(appDir);
        }`
```

Comment: Are you just asking why you get an error when messing with program files in non-admin mode:?

Comment: I expect it should write in Windows 7 virtual store in non-admin mode. So i am interested to know why its not writing in Virtual Store.

Comment: There is no "Virtual Store" thats never been a concept in Windows

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, apparently there is a "Virtual Store" that I just learned about from this article: http://portableapps.com/node/35519

Comment: @adv12 Interesting. I saw something like that in the super user link, but it appears to only work if you write to your *own* directory, where the OP is just writing to *any* directory.

Answer (score 0):

The "Program Files" directory is *protected* by UAC in Vista-onwards. Some discussion of this can be found at: [Why can't I edit a “Program Files” file on Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/384107/why-cant-i-edit-a-program-files-file-on-windows-7)

So its working as designed, you can't muck with Program Files as an external program unless  run as administrator. If you *intend* to always be run as administrator, add the following line to your app manifest:

```
 <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

That way you can double-click on the application, it will prompt for UAC access, and be run as Administrator.